# View all button to button of recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, view

Initially load 3 items from list after click on view all button load remaining all data to same page in kotlin.

To show 3 items I added limit to show data in adapter class in getItemCount mathod. So now I am able to see only 3 items from list. But not able to do like ad all data on same page on click view all button.

Comment: Initially you can pass list containing 3 items and when user clicks on view all button just update list and notify the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have solved the issue.

```
class MyAdapter(private val maxItems: Int = 3) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
    private val items = mutableListOf<String>()

    fun setData(data: List<String>) {
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(data)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return min(items.size, maxItems)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
    }

    fun updateMaxItems(max: Int) {
        maxItems = max
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_text)

    fun bind(text: String) {
        textView.text = text
    }
}
```

In your Activity/Fragment where you set up the RecyclerView, create a button "View All" and set its onClickListener

```
val viewAllButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.viewAllButton)
viewAllButton.setOnClickListener {
    //update the adapter's maxItems to show all items
    adapter.maxItems = Int.MAX_VALUE
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```